# Execution of a thread after it got interrupted

Tags: multithreading, thread-sleep

A thread is executing task to print numbers from 0 to n, and sleeps for 4000 ms after every print statement. Somewhere in the middle thread gets interrupted. Now when the same thread starts its execution, where will it start from , will it start printing the numbers from 0 to n again, or it will print numbers from where it got interrupted.
In both cases what are the reasons and how it is being handled?

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
   
        SleepTest sleepTest = new SleepTest();
        Thread thread = new Thread(sleepTest);
        thread.start();
        thread.interrupt();

    }
}
public class SleepTest implements Runnable{
static int sleep = 10;
    public void run(){
        for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
           System.out.println(i);

            try {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              Thread.sleep(4000);

            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {

                exception.printStackTrace();

            }
            System.out.println(Thread.interrupted());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a `interrupt()` on a thread object can only suggest thread to stop. It is not guarantee that the thread will stop.
It completely depends on the implementation of `run()` method of thread.

In your case in `run()` you are catching the `InterruptedException` and you are printing the exception trace but not stopping the thread.  Thats why thread will never stop on `InterruptedException` and continue the execution.
It may look like thread is getting stopped(by seeing exception trace) when see the output on console.

Refer [interrupt interrupted isinterrupted in Java](https://codepumpkin.com/interrupt-interrupted-isinterrupted-java-multithreading/)

Answer (score 2):

All `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` does is update the value of field `interrupted` to `true`.

Let's see the program's flow and how the `interrupted` field is assigned values:

```java
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       
            SleepTest sleepTest = new SleepTest();
            Thread thread = new Thread(sleepTest, "Sub Thread"); // Give a name to this thread
            thread.start(); // main thread spawns the "Sub Thread". Value of "interrupted" - false
            thread.interrupt(); // called by main thread. Value of "interrupted" - true
    
        }
    }
    public class SleepTest implements Runnable{
        static int sleep = 10;
        public void run(){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.interrupted()); // prints "Sub Thread true"
            for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
               System.out.println(i);
    
                try {
                  Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // no matter what value is for interrupted, it is assigned the value "true"
                  Thread.sleep(4000); // Can't call sleep with a "true" interrupted status. Exception is thrown. Note that, when the exception is thrown, the value of interrupted is "reset", i.e., set to false
    
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
    
                    exception.printStackTrace(); // whatever
    
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.interrupted()); // returns the value of interrupted and resets it to false
            }
        }
```

To answer

> where will it start from , will it start printing the numbers from 0
> to n again, or it will print numbers from where it got interrupted.

Calling interrupt will not cause make it start over because all it is doing at this call is set value `interrupted` to false (and not modifying anything else).